# Sailor flutter Invalid Parameter Type

Tags: flutter, dart

I use packages: Sailor and Cubit. When navigate to `realtionPage` have strange message in console:

`I/flutter (29427): [Sailor] WARNING : Invalid Parameter Type! 'relations' is declared with a type 'List<Relation>', but a 'List<Relation>' was passed!`

this is my Routes:

```
class Routes {
  static final sailor = Sailor();

  static void createRoutes() {
    sailor.addRoutes([
      SailorRoute(
        name: '/',
        builder: (context, args, params) {
          return RelationSearchPage();
        },
      ),
      SailorRoute(
        name: '/relationPage',
        builder: (context, args, params) {
          return RelationPage(params.param('relations'));
        },
        params: [SailorParam<List<Relation>>(name: 'relations')],
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

In Cubit class and state class I use explicitly `List<Relation>` not `dynamic`.
How understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done anything with Sailor, but reading the documentation i think you should do it like this:

```dart
class Routes {
  static final sailor = Sailor();

  static void createRoutes() {
    sailor.addRoutes([
      SailorRoute(
        name: '/',
        builder: (context, args, params) {
            return RelationSearchPage();
        },
      ),
      SailorRoute(
        name: '/relationPage',
        builder: (context, args, params) {
            return RelationPage();
        },
        params: [
            SailorParam<List<Relation>>(
                name: 'relations',
             // default: List<Relation>(),  You should add a default value!
            )
        ],
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

And use this to navigate to your RelationPage():

```
Routes.sailor.navigate<bool>("/relationPage", params: {
  'relations': yourListOfRelations; // Pass your List<Relations> here
});
```

And then use this in your RelationPage() to get the value of the param:

```dart
List<Relation> relations = Sailor.param<List<Relation>>(context, 'relations');
```